# Test all functions that have been terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron

I am developing a synchronizer between two databases (`SQL Server` and `MySQL`) with `ElectronJS` and `Node.JS` and everything is working fine, but I would like to execute the `window.close()` method to terminate the application when all tables are syncronized (which are done asynchronously within a `for` loop).

```js
// I removed error and bank connection treatments because they are working

// Read json file that contains all tables and its columns (keys)
fs.readFile(ABSPATH + 'tables.json', 'utf8', async (err,json) => {
  // Parse the content of the file into a JSON object
  let vetor = JSON.parse(json)
  // Foreach table
  for (let i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    // Read the table from SQL Server and save it falues into MySQL
    await read(vetor[i].table,vetor[i].keys)
  }
  // Instead of closing, I'm just displaying this message on screen (for debugging)
  document.body.innerHTML += "<h2>All data where inserted</h2>"
})
```

But as you can see, it is returning the final result before returning the functions, that is, they remain asynchronous:

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VvLx.jpg)

I believe my error is at the time of saving the data in the following function because I tested it with `console.log()`, but I still can't make it synchronous:

```js
con.connect(async err => {
  // Begin MySQL Transaction
  await con.beginTransaction(async err => {
    // Clear the table
    await con.query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${table}`, err => {})
    // Loop to insert all inputs into table
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        // Create and execute the query to input values into table
        await con.query(createInsert(table,keys,values[0]), err => {})
    }
    // When all data are inputed, end Transaction
    await con.commit(err => {
      // Write in window that everything gonna allright
      document.body.innerHTML += "<p>All data where successfully saved into " + table + ".</p>"
    })
  })
  // End MySQL Transaction
})
```

Comment: Mixing callbacks with promises is a recipe for disaster, I'd suggest you use `utils.promisify` or similar, convert all callbacks into promises and `await` them.

Answer (score 0):

Like georg had told me, the problem was that I was trying to await async functions, but the await only works with Promises.
I found the answer greetings to him and to [this answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406184/testar-se-todas-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ass%C3%ADncronas-foram-encerradas/406280#406280) that I had received on *StackOverflow in portuguese*.
So, I just put my connection into a Promise, like this:

```js
// Save datas into MySQL Database
function save(table, keys, values) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // MSSQL returns a JSON object filled with informations that I don't want
      // so I filter only what I want: the result of the query
    values = values.recordset
    // Start a new MySQL connection
    let con = mysql.createConnection({
      user:       OUSER,
      password:   OPASS,
      server:     OHOST,
      port:       OPORT,
      database:   ODB
    })
    con.connect(err => {
      if (err) {
        alert(err)
        window.close()
      }
      con.beginTransaction(err => {
        // This function is just for DontRepeatYourself
        rollBack(con, err, rej)

        con.query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${table}`, err => { rollBack(con, err, rej) })
        con.query(createInsert(table,keys,values[0]), err => { rollBack(con, err, rej) })
        con.commit(err => {
          rollBack(con, err, rej)
          document.body.innerHTML += `<p>All data where successfully registered into ${table}.</p>`
          res()
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```